# Simple question about setting enviromental variables in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I need to set the following env variable for Java VM in my EC2 micro instance:

```
[user]$ export LS_JAVA_OPTS=“-Xms500m -Xmx500m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1”
```

as per: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/resources/articles/logstash-tutorial/

However, when I use the command, I get:

```
-bash: export: `-Xmx500m': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1”': not a valid identifier
```

I googled problem, can't find solution, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use curly quotes, use straight quotes.

Comment: Always turn off "smart quotes" when working with code.

Comment: Thanks! that solved it. I thought I was going insane trying to figure it out. No idea why on the tutorial page they used those quotation characters.

Comment: Because they used a word processor with smart quotes, too.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes is wrong. Please try that;

```
export LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms500m -Xmx500m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1"
```

If will investigate same error please dont copy. Type the quote instead double quotes.

Comment: This should just be closed as a typo, not answered.